# Filter Panda according to dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to divide my panda in different sections by selecting date ranges.

I found the following solution online, but it is ignoring the year that I specified. Instead it gives me all entries between the specified dates, even though I (in this example) only want the entries for 2020. Any ideas?

**What I have**

```
start_date = "10/12/2020"
end_date = "10/15/2020"

after_start_date = df["Timestamp"] >= start_date
before_end_date = df["Timestamp"] <= end_date
between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]
filtered_dates
```

**What I get**

```
1   10/14/2020 
2   10/13/2020
3   10/12/2020
262 10/15/2019
263 10/14/2019
523 10/15/2018
784 10/13/2017
1044    10/14/2016
1045    10/13/2016 
etc.
```

**What I want**

```
1   10/15/2020 
2   10/14/2020 
3   10/13/2020 
4   10/12/2020
```

Comment: tested and working for me like `What I want`, because filtering by timestamp with year 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your data are not converted to datetimes:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

#default datetime format with YYYY-MM-DD
start_date = "2020-10-12"
end_date = "2020-10-15"

after_start_date = df["Timestamp"] >= start_date
before_end_date = df["Timestamp"] <= end_date
between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
filtered_dates = df.loc[between_two_dates]

print (filtered_dates)
   Timestamp
1 2020-10-14
2 2020-10-13
```

Comment: for starters, it helped to select the correct time frame, thank you.

the problem that I now have is that, the order of the newly formatted dates is mixed up and they are not in the right order. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

# Phase 2
p2_start_date = "2008-07-01"
p2_end_date = "2009-09-30"

after_p2_start_date = df["Timestamp"] >= p2_start_date
before_p2_end_date = df["Timestamp"] <= p2_end_date
between_two_p2_dates = after_p2_start_date & before_p2_end_date
cds_p2 = df.loc[between_two_p2_dates]`

`3139 2008-09-19
3140 2008-09-18
3141 2008-09-17 
3142 2008-09-16
3143 2008-09-15 
3144 2008-12-09 
3145 2008-11-09  
3146 2008-10-09 
3147 2008-09-09`

Comment: @CSBossmann - Are data in original order `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` ?

Comment: that was the problem! changed it in the csv and now its fine, thank you!